# Query that used to work in prior v2014 of SQL Server, dies in new v2019, and need Legacy Cardinality Estimator to fix. Is there a better way?

Tags: sql-server, cardinality-estimation

We've upgraded a SQL Server to 2019 from 2014.

In 2014 this query was fine:

```
INSERT INTO [schx].[US_New]
SELECT *
FROM [schx].[US_New_Stg]
WHERE FormattedID NOT IN (SELECT FormattedID
                          FROM [schx].[DLT]
                          WHERE [Type] = 'Hierarchical Root'
                         );
```

Upon upgrade (no code changes only SQL Server Upgrade), the query killed the process to which it belonged, instead of running for 4 minutes now it went on for 8 hours, and then it would time out.

We ended up adding this: `OPTION (USE HINT ( 'FORCE_LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION' ))` to the end of the query, and then things were fine again.

2 questions:

1. Because we have to use the Legacy CE, does this mean that the New CE one isn't as robust as the Legacy CE?
2. If instead of a subquery in the `WHERE` clause, we left-joined both and selected NOT NULL, would that remove the need for using the Legacy CE?

Thanks!

Comment: stats up to date? pls post query plans

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, 2 of the tables used here are only temporary (not TEMP tables) and they are removed when the processing is complete. So cannot quickly get the plan. Might have to set a Profiler on the next run and see if we can get it.